# AXLSX merge cells inside a style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm using ruby gem axlsx and want to know if there's a way to set merge columns inside a style? Today i doing like this:

```
sheet.merge_cells "A1:E1"
sheet.add_row [I18n.t('foo.some_label').upcase], style: [title]
sheet.merge_cells "B2:E2"
...
```

I want to avoid to increment the cells manually (B2:E2...B5:E5), there's a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you looking for a way to put it in a loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes give this a try (*Disclaimer I did not actually test these methods but I have used similar functionality in the past)

```
def merge_last_row(sheet,options ={})
  last_row = sheet.rows.last.index + 1
  first_col,last_col = options[:columns]
  if first_col && last_col
    sheet.merge_cells "#{first_col}#{last_row}:#{last_col}#{last_row}"
  else
    sheet.merge_cells sheet.rows.last
  end
  sheet.rows.last.style = style if options[:style]
end
```

so to do what you want it would be

```
merge_last_row sheet, columns:["A","E"]
sheet.add_row [I18n.t('foo.some_label').upcase]
merge_last_row sheet, columns:["B","E"], style:title
```

If the last row contains data in A-E then the columns can be left empty and it will merge the whole row. If it does not you could add an option for filling the columns like so

```
def fill_columns(sheet,column_count,options={})
  row = options[:row_data] || []
  (column_count - row.count).times do 
    row << nil
  end
  sheet.add_row row
end
```

calls as

```
my_row = ["Hello","World"]
fill_columns sheet, 5,row_data: my_row
# this will add a row like["Hello","World",nil,nil,nil]
# so that it will merge properly across the columns A-E
merge_last_row sheet
```

If you are going to use these consistently then patching these functions into `Worksheet` might make more sense so you don't have to pass the `sheet` object.

```
module Axlsx
  class Worksheet
    def merge_last_row(options={})
       last_row = rows.last.index + 1
       first_col,last_col = options[:columns]
       if first_col && last_col
         merge_cells "#{first_col}#{last_row}:#{last_col}#{last_row}"
       else
         merge_cells rows.last
       end
       rows.last.style = style if options[:style]
    end
    def fill_columns(column_count,options={})
      row_data = options[:row_data] || []
      (column_count - row.count).times do 
        row_data << nil
      end
      add_row row_data
    end
  end
end
```

Call

```
sheet.merge_last_row columns:["A","E"]
sheet.add_row [I18n.t('foo.some_label').upcase]
sheet.merge_last_row columns:["B","E"], style:title
```

Comment: the file with these methods should be on my mixin folder right?

Comment: @Rafael you can place them anywhere you like as long as you include them in the file you're using them in. For rails if you are using the patch methods you could place them in the initializers folder and then these methods will always be accessible.