# Rails Axlsx gem where to define functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the axlsx gem to create excel spreadsheets in my app.  I saw a very useful answer for one of my problems here:

[AXLSX merge cells inside a style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657513/axlsx-merge-cells-inside-a-style)

I would like to define a function that'll be available for all worksheets but I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: Check out the comment below the answer you have posted: "you can place them anywhere you like as long as you include them in the file you're using them in. For rails if you are using the patch methods you could place them in the initializers folder and then these methods will always be accessible. "
Doesn't that respond to your question? If not tell us more about your current setup and how you are using axlsx.

Comment: Your answer sounds good.  I'm pretty new to rails so I'm not sure how to go about it.  Is there some documentation you can point me at?

Comment: This is not my answer, but since you want to have this functionality on every single Worksheet, it suggests to place the code inside the `config/initializers/` folder of your app. The files inside that folder are loaded when your application server starts and placing the code inside a `module Axlsx` -> `class Worksheet` will patch those classes with your new function.
That will allow you to call your function like so: `worksheet_object.merge_last_row`

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.  If you write it out as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Happy to read that. Did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the comment below the answer you have posted: "you can place them anywhere you like as long as you include them in the file you're using them in. For rails if you are using the patch methods you could place them in the initializers folder and then these methods will always be accessible. "

Since you want to have this functionality on every single Worksheet, it suggests to place the code inside the config/initializers/ folder of your app. The files inside that folder are loaded when your application server starts and placing the code inside a

```
module Axlsx
  class Worksheet 
  end
end
```

will patch those classes with your new function. That will allow you to call your function like so: `worksheet_object.merge_last_row`