# Merge multiple cells of multiple rows using rails Axlsx

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, spreadsheet, axlsx

I have a rails application where i am trying to export some data in excel format. in my excel sheet i want to merge multiple cells of dynamic row. I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657513/axlsx-merge-cells-inside-a-style/23658760?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer but its giving me an error. Following the answer given in that solution i have created an`excel.rb` file inside my `config/initializers` directory and pasted this code

```
module Axlsx
  class Worksheet
    def merge_last_row(options={})
       last_row = rows.last.index + 1
       first_col,last_col = options[:columns]
       if first_col && last_col
         merge_cells "#{first_col}#{last_row}:#{last_col}#{last_row}"
       else
         merge_cells sheet.rows.last
       end
       rows.last.style = style if options[:style]
    end
    def fill_columns(column_count,options={})
      row_data = options[:row_data] || []
      (column_count - row.count).times do 
        row_data << nil
      end
      add_row row_data
    end
  end
end
```

and then in my `report.xls.axlsx` file i have the following code

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
xlsx_package.use_autowidth = true

wb.add_worksheet(name: "gold_sheet") do |sheet|
    @gold_live_console.each do |item|
        section = item.room.section.try(:name)
         time = item.bingning_inserted_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d - %l:%M %p")
        if section.present?
            sheet.add_row %w(Date)
            sheet.merge_last_row columns:["A","E"]
            sheet.add_row [time]
            sheet.add_row %w(  Section  )
            sheet.add_row [item.room.section.try(:name)]
            sheet.add_row %w(  Gra_Name  )
            sheet.add_row [item.room.gra_employee.try(:full_name)]
            sheet.add_row %w(Room# Credit Beginning_Status PM_Status Notes)
            sheet.add_row [item.room_location, item.room_credit, item.beginning_status]
            sheet.add_row()
        end
    end
end
```

When i run this it gives me `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method merge_last_row'` error

I want to merge all the columns from A to E for the Row with text Date

How should i use the above method in my axlsx file? I am new to ruby so sorry if my mistake is too silly but can anyone please point me out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Well it is nice to see my code is being used :). Can you please elaborate on the "error" since the part after what you have posted is very important e.g. *"undefined method merge_last_row [for XXX]"*

Comment: Hello @engineersmnky thanks for responding, this is the full error that i get undefined method `merge_last_row' for #<Axlsx::Worksheet:0x007f82a0139898> Did you mean?  merge_cells excluded from capture: DSN not set ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `merge_last_row' for #<Axlsx::Worksheet:0x007f82a0139898> Did you mean?  merge_cells):`

Comment: Have you restarted your sever since you added the initializer? Initializers are only loaded once at start up.

Comment: I have the same issue like the one in the previous question want to merge cells for dynamic row, your answer has six upvotes means it works, but for some reason its not working at my end and its giving me this error, i have place the `module` file in the initializers folder as u have mentioned in the comments of the previous question @engineersmnky

Comment: Yes but have you restarted your rails server since doing so

Comment: No i had not, and restarting the server did solve the problem thank you so much

Comment: Glad you got it working. If the `axlsx` code is working well for feel free to up vote my original answer.

Comment: I already did that, thank you again :) @engineersmnky