# Is there a way in gem Axlsx ruby gem to change the default font color (black) once for all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

With Axlsx you can add_style and give a cell or a row another color than the default one (black). Is there an easy way to set the default color of the worksheet (let's say to red) to avoid precising the row color each time ?

Comment: Have a look at [`axlsx_styler`](https://github.com/axlsx-styler-gem/axlsx_styler). Once you have generated the worksheet you can bulk apply the style after the fact.

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky, I actually use it in addition to Axlsx. You can actually add styles in bulk but it seems you need to know exactly where your first col, last col, and last row are to define the styles within an existing range

Comment: If you wanted to do this for the entire sheet then it is fairly simple to determine the range. Maybe this older post can help you with that https://stackoverflow.com/a/23658760/1978251

Comment: Well, I will try this solution. Thanks a lot @engineersmnky